# permission issue with npm init vue@latest in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, vue.js, vuejs3, ubuntu-20.04

I want to install vue 3 in a way that I choose the presets like [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#:%7E:text=%E2%9C%94%20Project%20name%3A%20%E2%80%A6%20%3Cyour,project%2Dname%3E...%0ADone.) in my wsl2 ubuntu.

What I did was:

1. sudo mkdir /var/www/myproj.com
2. cd /var/www/myproj.com
3. npm init vue@latest - but this one has `EACCESS: Permission denied error`
4. So I did sudo npm init vue@latest, but this one generates the error below

   ```
   npx: installed 1 in 3.153s
   /root/.npm/_npx/3489/lib/node_modules/create-vue/outfile.cjs:5681
     const isFeatureFlagsUsed = typeof (argv.default ?? argv.ts ?? argv.jsx ?? argv.router ?? 
   argv.pinia ?? argv.tests ?? argv.vitest ?? argv.cypress ?? argv.eslint) === "boolean";

   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
   at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
   at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
   at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
   ```

From here, I honestly don't know what to do.

**npm and node versions:**

```
npm = 6.14.16
node = v14.19.1
```

New to linux, so please bear with me :)

Answer (score 6):

I got exactly the same issue (at point 4) and updating to node 16 did the trick for me (I was still using the v12 btw).